# Correctly wrapping a NotImplemented operator

Tags: python, language-lawyer

I'm trying to correctly implement operator overloading by deferring to a different object *if* it is supported. However, so far I have only managed to figure out *unconditional* deferring, which behaves incorrectly in some edge cases, as demonstrated by the assertions below.

Is there any way to do this without reimplementing the interpreter's *entire* "subclass check, reflect, try twice if unrelated" dance? (note that the possibility of spoofed slot-wrappers makes that even more complicated, especially for operators not defined on `object` itself. I *think* that requires things like `type.__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(T)['__radd__']`, repeated for each T up the MRO until a match is found)

Note in particular that any use of `isinstance`, which my prior attempt used, would cause *most* of the assertions to fail, even though it fixed the current failure.

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Wrapper):
            other = other.obj
        # Wrong; should defer to other == self if NotImplemented.
        # Currently defers to other == self.obj instead.
        return self.obj == other

# some class that `Wrapper` doesn't know about
class Weird:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Wrapper):
            return True
        return NotImplemented

assert False == Wrapper(False)
assert Wrapper(False) == False
assert 0 == Wrapper(False)
assert Wrapper(False) == 0
assert 0.0 == Wrapper(False)
assert Wrapper(False) == 0.0
assert False == Wrapper(0)
assert Wrapper(0) == False
assert 0 == Wrapper(0)
assert Wrapper(0) == 0
assert 0.0 == Wrapper(0)
assert Wrapper(0) == 0.0
assert False == Wrapper(0.0)
assert Wrapper(0.0) == False
assert 0 == Wrapper(0.0)
assert Wrapper(0.0) == 0
assert 0.0 == Wrapper(0.0)
assert Wrapper(0.0) == 0.0
assert Weird() == Wrapper({})
assert Wrapper({}) == Weird(), 'this currently fails'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make Weird inherit from Wrapper, this works:

```
# some class that `Wrapper` doesn't know about
class Weird(Wrapper):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Wrapper):
            return True
        return NotImplemented
```

Comment: how about "Thanks for the help, I would also like the test `assert Weird() != Weird()` to pass, how would I do this?" instead of being rude?